# Kotlin use TikXml to parse XML file

Tags: android, kotlin, tikxml

i would like to parse xml file using TikXml library that seem nice : https://github.com/Tickaroo/tikxml .
However in the documentation i can't find how to use it.
I understand that i have to create a class modele.
Then i can instantiate the TikXml builder like this :

```
var tikXml = TikXml.Builder().build()
```

But i don't understand where do i have to add or specify witch class modele it's realated to and witch Xml file it has to read.
If anyone has already work with this lib, it would be nice if he can help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
 fun parseXML(bufferedSource: BufferedSource){
        val tikXml = TikXml.Builder().build()
        try {
            val tv = tikXml.read<TV>(bufferedSource, TV::class.java)
            println(tv)
        }catch(e:java.lang.Exception){
            println(e)
        }
    }
```

In the example above TV is my  data model that I created as you can see in their docs. You have to give tikXML a BufferedSource. In my case I got it from okhttp like this:

```
override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val bufferedSource = response.body?.source()
                try{
                    bufferedSource?.let { parseXML(it) }
                }catch(e:Exception){
                    println(e)
                }
            }
```

The lib can be a headache. Use this versions others have serious bugs:

```
   implementation 'com.tickaroo.tikxml:annotation:0.8.13'
    implementation 'com.tickaroo.tikxml:core:0.8.14-SNAPSHOT'
    kapt 'com.tickaroo.tikxml:processor:0.8.13'
```

I see you use Kotlin so make sure to use kapt.